# Diophantine equations whose coefficients are increasing sequences of integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I needed (for my research) to solve a Diophantine equation, in particular,
$$ 2 a + 3 b + 4 c + 5 d = 12 .$$
And I could easily solve it
(for example, on solution is $a=2, b=1, c=0, d=1$).
But this made me wonder if such equations, with their coefficients increasing sequences of
natural numbers, are a special case of Diophantine equations that are *always* explicitly solvable, 
despite the negative solution to Hilbert's 10th problem.

Comment: as long as some of the coefficents are relatively prime, we can use bezouts identity.

Comment: @maud: Thanks, I was ignorant of Bézout's identity, so I am glad to learn.  Does the identity apply when the right-hand-side number is arbitrary?

Comment: If they are relatively prime you can solve for any number, but if they are not you can only hit multiples of the GCD.

Comment: BTW, all multiples of the gcd can be achieved only if you allow negative values (which you probably do). If you allow only nonnegative values, only all *sufficiently large* multiples of the gcd can be so expressed; this is the [Frobenius number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html) or [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: dividing through by the gcd of the coefs reduces to the case where they have gcd = 1, where you can apply Bezout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linear Diophantine equations are always <strike>solvable</strike> decidable (in linear time).  If the coefficients are $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ then the numbers that can appear on the RHS are precisely the multiples of $\text{gcd}(a_1, ... a_n)$, and one can find solutions using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: +1.  Perhaps it would be better to say that linear Diophantine Equations are always "decidable", or clarify that to "solve" a Diophantine equation means to determine whether or not it has a solution.  Some might think (even me, perhaps) that an equation is "solvable" if it has a solution.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Generalizations

Comment: Thanks, Qiaochu (& Pete & Bill & Danny et al.).  I did not understand this before, but now I do!